# Why is my Django form not "valid"? Can't get the POST request to update database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to create a user profiles for users in my Django app. I have the form displaying where I want it to and when I try to submit, nothing happens.
I put a print statement after the form.is_valid in my view.py and found that it wasn't 'valid' but I have no idea why.
I have tried several different ways to 'clean' / 'validate' data but I can't get past the form being 'invalid.'

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

urls:

```
path('userinfo/', views.user_info, name='userinfo')
```

form template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load bootstrap4 %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <h1>Enter User Info</h1>
<form method="POST" class="form">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {% bootstrap_form form %}

 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create Profile">

 </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

view:

```
def user_info(request):

form = ProfileForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()

return render(request, 'miraDashboard/form.html', context={'form': form})
```

model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField("Full Name", max_length=1024)
    job_role = models.CharField("Role", max_length=254, default="Seeking Job Opportunities")
    zip_code = models.CharField("Zip Code", max_length=5)
    user_image = models.ImageField("Upload Profile Picture", upload_to='images/')
def __str__(self):
    return f'{self.user.username} Profile'
```

form:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Profile

class ProfileForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['name','job_role','zip_code', 'user_image']
```

Comment: Could you try to replace <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create Profile"> with <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Profile</button>?

Comment: I tried this but nothing changed.

Comment: Try add "enctype="multipart/form-data" to form like: <form method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

Answer (score 11):

if you want to see errors in form change else statmant:

```
def user_info(request):

form = ProfileForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    else:
        print(form.errors.as_data()) # here you print errors to terminal


return render(request, 'miraDashboard/form.html', context={'form': form})
```

after form.is_valid() you don't need to set it again (form = ProfileForm() in else statment). this way your form will get errors( you cen see them in form.errors).

Comment: I tried this and got: {'user_image': [ValidationError(['This field is required.'])]}...that helps a lot in narrowing down what I need to look at! Gonna try to figure out why that is the case. Thank you so much!

Comment: if you dont want uploading img just change your model field user_image to : models.ImageField("Upload Profile Picture", upload_to='images/', blank=True, null=True)

Comment: I need the image for profiles. I think my form.html file needs adjusting to know where to send the image when I hit create profile. Still figuring that out.

Comment: One of the dangers using a common lang type as 'type' as your field: I kept getting {'type': [ValidationError ....} and I couldn't figure out why it wasn't giving me a field name ... when it actually was. Try not to miss this if you're boneheaded like me. ;-)